# Gradle build failing with fabric crashlytics when minify is enabled in Android studio version 3.2 and Gradle version 4.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

Getting the following errors after applying **proguard rules**:

> Could not find method create() for arguments
>   [crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease, class
>   com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask,
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@1711854a]
>   on task set of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

Comment: I think you update your studio with higher version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the version of fabric build tools in your build.gradle is set to something like `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'` which means it always uses the newest available version.

The current version 1.26.0 seems broken so you can temporarily set exact version to 1.25.4: `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'`.

Checked a couple of minutes ago, it works.

**UPD:** new version io.fabric.tools(1.26.1) is released. `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'` now works well

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I was previously using it like 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'.

Comment: version 1.26.1 is released and fixes the problem